# angular2 ngfor child component elements

Tags: angular

I have an Angular2 component (PropertyComponent) which is used with an attribute selector for each row of a bootstrap table:

```
<tbody>
  <tr app-property *ngFor="let property of properties" [property]="property"></tr>
</tbody>
```

I would like to style the `<tr>` row by adding a class based on the contents of the property object. Which I cannot do as it stands because I would like to put the style logic into the PropertyComponent. I could change the code to use the component selector:

```
<tbody>
  <app-property *ngFor="let property of properties" [property]="property"></app-property>
</tbody>
```

and put the `<tr>` tags into the component template, but this causes formatting issues due to the extra `<app-property>` tags which wrapped around the table rows.

The PropertyComponent contains:

```
<td>{{property.key}}</td>
<td>{{property.value}}</td>
...
```

Is there a nice way to solve this problem?

Comment: can you give an example of the `property` contents ?

Comment: Yep - it's just a couple of `<td>`s + some other code to allow editing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for `HostBinding` which allows you to bind properties in the parent element of your angular component.

```
@HostBinding('class.some-class') someClass = true;
```

Note that setting it to true will apply it.

Comment: please add more details how to use HostBinding in this case

Answer (score 2):

Base on the `property`, you can use [[ngClass]](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) directive to apply the appropriate class. Here is the updated code:

---

```
<table>
    <tbody *ngFor="let property of properties" 
            app-property [property]="property">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have put the `*ngFor` in `<tbody>`, it will put each row in a `<tbody>` tag. It may look as an ugly solution but it will serve the purpose for your case.

---

I don't know how your `PropertyComponent` looks exactly, but I'll regenerate it with minimum required code:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[app-property]',
  template: `
        <tr [ngClass]="getPropertyRowStyle()">
            <td>{{property.key}}</td>
            <td>{{property.value}}</td>
        </tr> 
    `,
    styles: [`
                .class-one{ color:red; }
                .class-two{ color:green; }
            `]
})
export class PropertyComponent {
  @Input() property: any;

  getPropertyRowStyle(){
      // implement your logic here to return the appropriate class.
      // e.g. 
      if(this.property.key === 'one') {
          return 'class-one';
      }
      else if(this.property.key === 'two') {
          return 'class-two';
      }
  }
}
```

I am using the `getPropertyRowStyle()` method to get the `[ngClass]` according to the `property` values. You can implement your own logic in that method. Also, I have put the `<tr>` tag inside the component as you needed.

---

Here is a link to working [**PLUNKER DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Pl0YpdXeHao1V5BUjERB?p=preview)

Comment: Hmm, that looks like it would work, but the logic is a little more complicated than that, and I'd like to put it into the PropertyComponent

Comment: since you want to add styles to the `<tr>`, I would suggest to use the `ngClass` there. I am not sure what do you mean when you say "logic is a little more complicated"

Comment: The logic which decides which class that I should apply to the row is more complex than simply looking at the property key/value. There are other fields that are used to pick the class. I would like to put the 'tr' (and class styling) into the PropertyComponent.

Comment: Then You can use a funtion to get the styles in tr. I will update my answer in a while.

Comment: But that has multiple `<tbody>` tags.... I'm beginning to think that the issue is elsewhere, because I can't reproduce the problem in plunker.....

Comment: where is your plunker link ?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/d7nERojjYe7tYDtfTV2I?p=preview - but as I say, it's working there.....

Comment: that is just plain html. Where is the angular code ?

Comment: have you tried my solution? That works for your case !

Comment: It's better, but the styling is still 'wrong' the column margins/padding is gone - it's as if bootstrap can't handle the extra element between the tr and the td

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, this is what you're looking for:

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let property of properties">
    <app-property [property]="property"></app-property>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

This way you will have access to the `property` on the `<tr></tr>` tags. So you could do something like this

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let property of properties" [class.active]="property.name === 'potato">
    <app-property [property]="property"></app-property>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, the nested `<app-property>` tag is still messing up the table formatting - all my columns are 'squashed' to the left.

Comment: Sounds like you're having CSS issues then. Is there nothing weird going on with the tr width?

Comment: The tr looks fine to me - but the 'td' are all 'squashed' - and the problem goes away when I eliminate the 'app-property' element